# What is the derivative of this integral?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have asked this question here 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536018/how-to-find-derivative-of-this-intergral

but still has no response.

Might I ask it here ?

Let $\alpha(t)\in\{0,1\}: 0\leq t\leq 1$ be a two state continuous Markov chain
with the generator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain)

$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\alpha & \alpha;\\
\beta &-\beta\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume that $\alpha(t)=i \in\{0,1\}$.  Let $$f(t)=\int_t^1\mathbb{I}_{\{\alpha(u)=1\}}(u) du $$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function.

My questions:

1)  How to find $\frac{df}{dt}$

2) Can we find the density function of $f(t)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The first question is easy: the derivative of $f(t)$ is just $-\alpha(t)$ (except on the almost surely discrete set of points where $\alpha(t)$ has a jump discontinuity, where $f(t)$ is nondifferentiable). This is explained by the trivial observation that $\mathbb{I}_{\{\alpha(u)=1\}}(u)=\alpha(u)$, so a simpler way to write $f(t)$ is
$$f(t)=\int_t^1 \alpha(u)\  du. $$

The second question is much more technical, and I'm not sure a closed form could be found for the density of $f(t)$ (also note that, as pointed out on the Mathematics Stack Exchange version of the question, the answer depends on the initial condition $\alpha(0)$, so there are essentially two answers, one when $\alpha(0)=0$ and one when $\alpha(1)=1$; for the most general case of a random initial condition you would then take the appropriate weighted average of those two densities). The way I would approach this is by first trying to compute the moments
$$ \mu_n = \mu_n(t) = \mathbb{E}(f(t)), \qquad (n\ge 0), $$
then using them to get the characteristic function (a.k.a. Fourier transform)
$$ \phi_{f(t)}(s) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i s f(t)}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i^n f(t)^n \mu_n }{n!},
$$
and then computing the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi_{f(t)}(s)$ to get the density. Now, to compute $\mu_n$, write it as a multiple integral, namely
$$
\mu_n = \int_t^1 \ldots \int_t^1 \mathbb{E}(\alpha(u_1)\cdots \alpha(u_n))\ du_n \cdots du_1
= \int_t^1 \ldots \int_t^1 g(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \ du_n \cdots du_1,
$$
where I denote $g(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\mathbb{E}(\alpha(u_1)\cdots \alpha(u_n)) = \mathbb{P}(\alpha(u_1)=\ldots=\alpha(u_n)=1)$. So the whole thing boils down to computing $g(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$.
If we assume the initial condition $\alpha(0)=i_0 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, then (for $u_1 < \ldots < u_n $)
we have slightly more generally that for $i_1,\ldots,i_n\in\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$,
$$ \mathbb{P}(\alpha(u_1)=i_1,\ldots,\alpha(u_n)=i_n) = p_{u_1}(i_0,i_1)
p_{u_2}(i_1,i_2),
\cdots
p_{u_n}(i_{n-1},i_n)
$$
where $p_u(i,j)$ denotes the transition kernel of the Markov chain (I think this is expressed in terms of matrix exponentials as $p_u(i,j) = v_i e^{u Q} v_j^\top$ where $v_0=(1,0)$, $v_1=(0,1)$, and $Q$ is the infinitesimal generator defined in the question, but given the late hour I could be getting this part wrong; in particular I may be mixing up the order of $i$ and $j$).

This concludes the probabilistic part of the answer. The remaining part is to do the calculations, hopefully that can be done and some useful result can be obtained this way. (By the way, this question is about a fairly important and natural Markov chain, so I wouldn't be too surprised if the answer to the question is known.)

Comment: Dear Dan, thank you so much for your time answering my question. Please let me read and understand your answer before accepting. Thank you for your patience !

Comment: No problem. Actually, since my answer is incomplete, it may be better if you do not accept it, in case somebody else finishes the job or has a better idea how to attack the question, or gives a reference to a solution.